# Select's width doesn't correspond with max-width when being in table

Tags: css

I have a #wrapper div, with max-width:50%, then a table inside and a select, with max-width:100%.

But despite this, the select is still too wide, example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gLqecmhu/11/ why is that and how can I do it? I want it to make it mobile friendly.

Code:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
}
table {
  max-width: 100%;
}
select {
  max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id = 'wrapper'>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>Very long option Very long option Very long option Very long option Very long option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` use to mobile friendly in small devices.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work, neither on `select` nor `select option` nor `table`, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/zYqzOpN), to show case the effect of `max-width` on different sized elements.

Add `width: 100%;`, to each rule and boom it works. I'd however recommend you to use `@media` queries at some point since the wrapper will always stay half the screen size.

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
select {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrapper'>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>Very long option Very long option Very long option Very long option Very long option</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You could also remove the rule for the `table` since it's width is defined by its content. E.g.

```
#wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed, although I still don't get it :) Why the `max-width` didn't work o.O mdn clearly says: > _The max-width CSS property sets the maximum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by max-width._

Comment: @konrados. I wrote a codepen the showcase the effect of `max-width` on different sized elements. https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/zYqzOpN

Comment: @konrados This makes part of contents of `option` invisible on small screens. The part of `option` which is wider than the screen is just off-screen. Shorten the `option`. Test on mobile